# For NVD3 lineChart Remove Missing Values (to be able to interpolate)

Tags: nvd3.js, linechart, missing-data

I am using NVD3 to visualise data on economic inequality. The chart for the US is here: http://www.chartbookofeconomicinequality.com/inequality-by-country/USA/

These are two lineCharts on top of each other. The problem I have is that there are quite a lot of missing values and this causes two problems:

If I would not make sure that the missing values are not visualised the line Chart would connect all shown values with the missing values. Therefore I used the following to not have the missing values included in the line chart:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
            .y(function(d) { return d[1]== 0 ? null : d[1]; })
```

But still if you hover over the x-axis you see that the missing values are shown in the tooltip on mouseover. Can I get rid of them altogether? Possibly using remove in NVD3?

The second problem is directly related to that. Now the line only connects values of the same series when there is no missing values in between. That means there are many gaps in the lines. Is it possible to connect the dots of one series even if there are missing values in between?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use `.defined()` like this: `.defined(function(d) { return d[1] != null })`. Not sure if that will give you exactly what you want but worth a try.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you for your reply! It was helpful and I got one step further but I'm not yet there. In order to make this thread more informative and to make clear what I am trying to do I built a small example in JS fiddle. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xammamax/8Kk8v/ There are some missing values in one of the time series. What I'd like to do is to connect the two non-missing values before and after the missing values. So that in the end all values are shown by the markers and all of the values of the series are visually connected.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kk8v/1/) where all the missing values are removed?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I want. But it is unfortunately only a solution when the data is presented in json. Is there also a way to achieve the same when I'm reading the data from a csv file? What do I do when the row refers to a particular year when there is data for some but not all series? (I would use jsfiddle if I knew how to include a csv file there.)

Comment: It sounds like you would need to convert it to a structure like the JSON that you can filter.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @LarsKotthoff ! As this is a different issue than the one solved here, I asked this new question related to csv data here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402813/read-csv-data-into-nvd3-linechart-but-exclude-missing-values-so-that-nvd3-visua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lars showed, getting the graph to look the way you want is just a matter of removing the missing values from your data arrays.

However, you wouldn't normally want to do that by hand, deleting all the rows with missing values.  You need to use an [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to remove the missing values from your data arrays.

Once you have the complete data array as an array of series objects, each with an array of values, this code should work:

```
//to remove the missing values, so that the graph
//will just connect the valid points,
//filter each data array:
data.forEach(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.filter(
        function(d){return d.y||(d.y === 0);}
    );
    //the filter function returns true if the
    //data has a valid y value 
    //(either a "true" value or the number zero,
    // but not null or NaN)

});
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xammamax/8Kk8v/

Of course, when you are constructing the data array from a csv where each series is a separate column, you can do the filtering at the same time as you create the array:

```
var chartdata = [];//initialize as empty array

d3.csv("top_1_L-shaped.csv", function(error, csv) {

    if (error)
        return console.log("there was an error loading the csv: " + error);

    var columndata = ["Germany", "Switzerland", "Portugal", 
                      "Japan", "Italy", "Spain", "France", 
                      "Finland", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Netherlands"];

    for (var i = 0; i < columndata.length; i++) {

        chartdata[i].key = columndata[i];

        chartdata[i].values = csv.map(function(d) {
                return [+d["year"], +d[ columndata[i] ] ];
            })
            .filter(function(d){
                return d[1]||(d[1] === 0);
            });
            //the filter is applied to the mapped array, 
            //and the results are assigned to the values array.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @AmeliaBR! That works! (Although I had to change one thing but I'm not sure why. If I use the line 'return d[1]||(d[1] === 0);' it won't work (the missing values are included in the loaded data). But if I use 'return d[1]||(d[1] != 0);' then it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! [Here](http://www.chartbookofeconomicinequality.com/inequality-by-country/usa/) is the result if someone is interested.

Comment: Ah, I see.  When you do `+d[ columndata[i] ]`, it converts the null values to zero.  So my effort to distinguish "true" zero values from null values fails before you even get to the filter.  If you are sure that you will never have *valid* zero values, you can just use `return d[1];` for the filter.  If you want to separate zero from null, you'll need to change the map function as well, to use `parseFloat(d[ columndata[i] ])` instead of the `+` conversion operator.  `parseFloat` will return `NaN` for null values or empty strings; the + conversion returns 0.